Finding the equations of the lines tangent to $Ax^2+2Bxy+Cy^2+2Dx+2Ey+F=0$ and parallel to $Gx+Hy+I=0$
A curve $Ax^2+2Bxy+Cy^2+2Dx+2Ey+F=0$ and a line $Gx+Hy+I=0$ are given. How do I find the equation of the tangent (tangents) to a given curve that is (are) parallel to a given line?

Differentiate the curve's equation. The value you get is the slope of the tangent line. This will be equal to the slope of the original line with which you're comparing.

The first clue is that every parallel line has the form
$$ G x + H y + J = 0 \tag{1} $$
which means that the problem is solved once $J$ is found. The problem is that (1) is used to find $J$, once the tangent point $(x,y)$ is known.
So we need to find the tangent point $(x,y)$ from the two equations given.
This is done by first matching the slopes of the two curves
$$ \begin{aligned}
 \frac{{\rm d}y}{{\rm d}x} & = - \frac{A x+B y+D}{B x+C y+E} & & \text{conic} \\
 \frac{{\rm d}y}{{\rm d}x} & = - \frac{G}{H} & & \text{line} \\
\end{aligned} \tag{2}$$
the above is a line through the center of the conic that cuts the curve at the tangent point.
This line has the equation
$$ (A H - B G) x + (B H - C G) y + (D H - E G) = 0 $$
and we can bring it to the $y= m x +b $ form in order to substitute into the conic equation
$$ \begin{aligned}
  m & = \frac{ A H - B G }{C G - B H} \\
  b & = \frac{ D H - E G}{C G - B H} \\
  & y  = m x + b
\end{aligned} \tag{3}$$
Using (3) in the equation of the conic eliminates $y$ and we can group into three coefficients $(u,v,w)$ that separate the powers of $x$
$$ \begin{aligned}
 u & = A+m\left(2B+mC\right)\\
 v & = B\,b+C\,b\,m+D+E\,m\\
 w & = C\,b^{2}+2E\,b+F\\
 &  u\, x^2 + 2\, v\, x + w = 0
\end{aligned} \tag{4}$$
with solution
$$ x = 
\begin{cases} 
\dfrac{-v+\sqrt{v^2-u\, w}}{u} \\ \dfrac{-v -\sqrt{v^2-u\, w}}{u} \end{cases} \tag{5}$$
and $$y = m x + b$$ from(3) and finally
$$ I = -G x - H y $$
